# Does anyone know how to count the TR in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination, html-table

This is the JQuery for the table paging:

```
    $('document').ready(function(){
    function pagination(){
            var req_num_row=1;
            var $tr=jQuery('tbody tr');
            var total_num_row=$tr.length;
            var num_pages=0;
            if(total_num_row % req_num_row ==0){
                num_pages=total_num_row / req_num_row;
            }
            if(total_num_row % req_num_row >=1){
                num_pages=total_num_row / req_num_row;
                num_pages++;
                num_pages=Math.floor(num_pages++);
            }
            for(var i=1; i<=num_pages; i++){
                jQuery('#pagination').append(" "+i+" ");
            }
            $tr.each(function(i){
                jQuery(this).hide();
                if(i+1 <= req_num_row){
                    $tr.eq(i).show();
                }

            });
            jQuery('#pagination a').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $tr.hide();
                var page=jQuery(this).text();
                var temp=page-1;
                var start=temp*req_num_row;
                //alert(start);

                for(var i=0; i< req_num_row; i++){

                    $tr.eq(start+i).show();

                }
            });
        }
    jQuery('document').ready(function(){
        pagination();

    });
```

Everything works as it should with this pagination except it considers the length of the tr, counting td/rows. What I want is to count just the tr blocks, not the td rows. Is this possible ?

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking or what specific problem is. Perhaps all you want is visible rows?

Comment: use regexp with <tr> but escape the < and > char  global and multiline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rows = $('table tr').length
```

I believe this will work. But that´s what you are doing. Sorry, i looked now.

It´s not working?

```js
$('<p>$(\'table tr\').children().length = ' + $('table tr').children().length + '</p>').appendTo('body');

$('<p>$(\'table tr\').length = ' + $('table tr').length + '</p>').appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td>TD</td>
            <td>TD</td>
            <td>TD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TD</td>
            <td>TD</td>
            <td>TD</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Nope, does the same job :D Thanks...

Comment: You want to count how many tr tags are in the table, right?

Comment: yes, correct, let me try again, something went wrong with my browser i didn't saw everything, sorry.

Comment: Yes, that's working. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to use:

```
var num_rows = jQuery("table").find("tbody").children().length;
```

I think that should work!

Comment: It's not working, its counting the tr > td (rows) again, same. Thanks for the answer. I need to count just the tr tags/blocks.